# Does it make sense to call .AsNoTracking for OData GET controller actions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata

There is `.AsNoTracking()` method in EF Core which ensures minimal memory usage and optimal performance for read operation. When I found examples of OData controllers online, I've never seen using `.AsNoTracking()` for `Get` and `Get(id)` methods. For example, in MS docs both

- OData for .NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/tutorials/basic-crud
- OData for .NET Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

don't use it.

So, does it make sense to use it for OData read queries?

Comment: Well, maybe they thought the db context usage optimization belonged to another document. They just wanted to mention how you use the db context in an odata controller. The answer is yes anywhere you won't modify an entity it is better to use `AsNoTracking()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries):

> No-tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They're generally quicker to execute because there's no need to set up the change tracking information. If the entities retrieved from the database don't need to be updated, then a no-tracking query should be used.

Since your `Get` OData endpoint is readonly and I assume does not rely on navigation properties fix up for earlier queried data on the context (i.e. for example you are not trying to perform `AsSplitQuery()` "manually" by querying one entity first and then another which has relations to it) then you should use `AsNoTracking`.

Note that docs and especially examples do not always cover all possible related stuff (for example, regarding performance, architecture, best practices), quite often they are quick and dirty examples and sometimes use anti-patterns or even can be plain wrong (here are some examples of latter which I've discovered/fixed myself - [github PR 1](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8228), [github PR 2](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/33589), [github PR 3](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/8965)).

Answer (score 0):

AsNoTracking prevents creation of the tracking objects which "ensures minimal memory usage and optimal performance for read operation". At the same time, it ensures no change can be saved. So, you need to use AsNoTracking whenever you don't need to save changes.

I guess AsNoTracking is avoided in most examples because saving of modification can't be assumed as absent.

Comment: OData GET actions are not designed to have modifications